# If $\sin^2 A= \sin^2 B+\sin^2 C$, then the triangle is :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\sin^2 A= \sin^2 B+\sin^2 C$, then the triangle is :

$1$. Equilateral

$2$. Isosceles

$3$. Acute angled triangle

$4$. Right angled triangle.

My Attempt:

$$\sin^2 A=\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C$$
$$1-\cos^2 A=1-\cos^2 B+ 1-\cos^2 C$$
$$\cos^2 A -\cos^2 B - \cos^2 C= -1$$

How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sine theorem $\sin^2 A=\sin^2 B+\sin^2 C$ implies $a^2=b^2+c^2$, so the given triangle is a right triangle with $\widehat{BAC}=90^\circ$, by the (converse) Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: by the law of sines $\sin A = \cfrac{a}{2 R}\,$ and similar for the others. Then by Pythagoras' $\;\cdots$

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I didn't understand.

Comment: @Maxwell Lookup the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines). Then substitute the above into the given relation, factor out the common denominator of $4 R^2\,$,  and you get $a^2=b^2+c^2$ where $a,b,c$ are the lengths of the sides. That makes the triangle a right one by [Pythagoras' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Comment: Not by Pythagoras - by inverse Pythagoras.

Comment: @dxiv What is $R$?

Comment: @Alex You mean the *converse* of Pythagoras. Right, though it depends on what you consider to be *the* theorem. It's sometimes stated as $a^2=b^2+c^2$ *iff* the triangle is a right triangle.

Comment: @mrnovice $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the law of sines together with the given condition:
$$
{a\over\sin A} = {b\over\sin B} = {c\over\sin C} , \quad
\sin^2 A =\sin^2 B +\sin^2 C \quad\Rightarrow\quad a^2=b^2+c^2.
$$
Therefore you have a right triangle by the [converse of the Pythagorean theorem](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/geometry/right-triangles-and-trigonometry/the-converse-of-the-pythagorean-theorem-and-special-triangles).

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin^2A-\sin^2B=\sin^2C$$
$$\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2C$$
$$\sin C(\sin(A-B)-\sin C)=0$$
$$\sin C(2\cos(\frac{A+C-B}{2})(\sin (\frac{A-(C+B)}{2})=0$$

Further hint: $A+C=\pi-B$ and $B+C=\pi-A$

Comment: I didn't get the amswer. Please elaborate..